# Извлечение значений типа double из строки

Tags: android, android-studio, геокодирование

Работаю с Api yandex-geocoder. В ответе от сервера приходит строка с координатами, в которой сначала указывается долгота (lon), а затем широта (lat). Например: "36.587223 50.59566". Мне нужно извлечь эти 2 значения из типа String, поместить их в тип double и поменять местами, чтобы первое значение приходило в переменную lat, а второе - в переменную lon. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно осуществить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала можно будет разбить строку на строковый массив по пробелам:

```
String a = your string;
String[] array = a.split(" ");
```

У нас получится массив с двумя элементами - вашими координатами. Потом запишем в две переменные типа double:

```
double defaultLon = Double.parseDouble(array[0]);
double defaultLat = Double.parseDouble(array[1]);
```

Теперь у вас есть две переменные - долгота и широта и вы можете их использовать дальше. Если вам нужна опять строка то можно сделать так:

```
String answer = "" + defaultLat + " " + defaultLon;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался!